# Are craftable traps a viable option?

Tags: fallout-4

How viable of a weapon are the craftable traps for adventuring?
The items I'm talking about:

- Caltrops
- Poisoned caltrops
- Bear trap
- Bleeding bear trap

Do they receive bonus damage from any of the basic damage perks, like Demolition Expert? They seem a bit mine-like.

Or will I just get frustrated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, all those items have fixed damage outputs, and the *Demolition Expert* perk only affects things that explode, most notably grenades and mines.

- But! check out [the video here](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/yal82j/planting_caltrops_instead_of_grenades_or_mines/): someone pickpockets an enemy, leaves a caltrop in their inventory, and they almost instantly die. Silently. You'll need the second tier of the [*Pickpocket*](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Pickpocket_(Fallout_4)) perk for this.
- A lot of Fallout 4 players create Poisoned Caltrops only to sell them for a nice profit (see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/og0glf/poison_caltrops_an_efficient_way_to_turn_steel/): 5 Steel = 1 Poisoned Caltrop / 200 Steel = 200 bottle caps / 40 Poisoned Caltrops = 1600 bottle caps).
- There is a mod, [*Far Harbor Trap Overhaul*](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/15380/?tab=description), which overhauls all of the items you mention, to make the role they were meant to play more appealing.
  There is a simpler mod that only changes the properties of the Bear Trap: [Improved Bear Traps](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/16867/?tab=description).
- You might still get frustrated—that's something I can't control, unfortunately.

Comment: Wow! If i ever want to make pickpovketing sneaker, i will remember this! Marking this as the answer since it provides some good uses for (poisoned) caltrops